# Find standard deviation of row values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

Let's say I have a DataFrame as follows

`raw_df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,1,1,1],[2,3,4,5],[4,8,12,16]], ["A","B","C","D"])`

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  3|  4|  5|
|  4|  8| 12| 16|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I need to compute standard deviation of the all row values and display it in a new column (as shown below)

```
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|              std|
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+
|  1|  1|  1|  1|              0.0|
|  2|  3|  4|  5|1.118033988749895|
|  4|  8| 12| 16| 4.47213595499958|
+---+---+---+---+-----------------+
```

I have tried creating a udf but I am getting errors. Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F, types as T
import numpy as np

def std_dev(*args):
    return np.std(*args)

std_dev_udf = F.udf(std_dev, T.DoubleType())

raw_df.withColumn("std", std_dev_udf(F.array(*raw_df.columns))).show()
```

Error Stack:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2707.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 94.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 94.0 (TID 127) (host.docker.internal executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype). This happens when an unsupported/unregistered class is being unpickled that requires construction arguments. Fix it by registering a custom IObjectConstructor for this class.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Calculate Standard deviation row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077107/spark-calculate-standard-deviation-row-wise)

Comment: @werner It does! I just had to tweak it to include multiple arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the ways to do it. You can join back the final dataframe back with original based on `uniqueId`.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


raw_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,1,1,1],
                                     [2,3,4,5],
                                     [4,8,12,16]],
                                    ["A","B","C","D"])

raw_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("uniqueId", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("num_array", F.array(["A","B","C","D"]))
raw_df = raw_df.select("uniqueId", "num_array").withColumn("exploded_num", F.explode(F.col("num_array"))).drop(F.col("num_array"))
raw_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

raw_df = raw_df.groupby("uniqueId").agg(F.stddev_pop("exploded_num"))
raw_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---+---+---+---+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |1  |1  |1  |
|2  |3  |4  |5  |
|4  |8  |12 |16 |
+---+---+---+---+

+--------+------------+
|uniqueId|exploded_num|
+--------+------------+
|0       |1           |
|0       |1           |
|0       |1           |
|0       |1           |
|1       |2           |
|1       |3           |
|1       |4           |
|1       |5           |
|2       |4           |
|2       |8           |
|2       |12          |
|2       |16          |
+--------+------------+

+--------+------------------------+
|uniqueId|stddev_pop(exploded_num)|
+--------+------------------------+
|0       |0.0                     |
|1       |1.118033988749895       |
|2       |4.47213595499958        |
+--------+------------------------+
```